# Reuse binding in Rust closure

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am attempting to generate a `Vec<(Point, f64)>`:

```
let grid_size = 5;

let points_in_grid = (0..grid_size).flat_map(|x| {
    (0..grid_size)
        .map(|y| Point::new(f64::from(x), f64::from(y)))
        .collect::<Vec<Point>>()
});

let origin = Point::origin();

let points_and_distances = points_in_grid
    .map(|point| (point, point.distance_to(&origin)))
    .collect::<Vec<(Point, f64)>>();
```

I get the following error:

```
use of moved value: point
```

I understand that I cannot use `point` in both elements of the tuple, but when I attempt to store a reference, I get an error regarding lifetime.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete compilable (even with an error) example, preferably which will work on play.rust-lang.org?  It would be easier to be sure what error you're getting and where, and to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming your `Point` struct looks like the following:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point(f64, f64);

impl Point {
    fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Self { Point(x, y) }
    fn origin() -> Self { Point(0.,0.) }
    fn distance_to(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        ((other.0 - self.0).powi(2) + (other.1 - self.1).powi(2)).sqrt()
    }
}
```

Now let's look at an even simpler example that will not compile:

```
let x = Point::new(2.5, 1.0);
let y = x;
let d = x.distance_to(&y);
```

Which gives the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
  --> <anon>:15:13
   |
14 |     let y = x;
   |         - value moved here
15 |     let d = x.distance_to(&y);
   |             ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `Point`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Because `x` has been moved into `y`, it now can't have a reference taken in order to call the `distance_to` function.

The important thing to note here is that order matters - if we swap the lines over we can call `distance_to` by borrowing `x`, the borrow will end and *then* `x` can be moved into `y`.

```
let x = Point(0., 0.);
let d = x.distance_to(&y);
let y = x; // compiles
```

In your case, a very similar thing is happening when constructing the tuple. `point` gets moved into the tuple, and *then* tries to borrow it to form the second element. The simplest solution is to do the same thing as here: swap the order of the elements of the tuple.

```
let points_and_distances = points_in_grid
    .map(|point| (point.distance_to(&origin), point))
    .collect::<Vec<(f64, Point)>>(); // compiles
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3b8ecd52fb0e1b7bee3b0b7ce89f539f&version=stable&backtrace=1)

N.B. if you want to retain the order:

```
.map(|(a, b)| (b, a))
```

Comment: Said another way, `Point` does not implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). You could also use a temporary variable - `.map(|point| { let d = point.distance_to(&origin); (point, d) })`.